# Postgresql add check for empty array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to add a limitation rule to a table

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    id                        serial not null primary key,
    values1                   smallint[] not null DEFAULT ARRAY [12, 20],
    values2                   smallint[] not null DEFAULT ARRAY [],

    CONSTRAINT constraint_check_error CHECK (values1 NOT ( IS NULL OR values1 = '{}') AND NOT (values2 IS NULL OR values2 = '{}') )
);
```

to avoid the the tables `values1`and `values2` being empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need `NOT ( IS NULL...` in constraint, because you already have `not null` in your table definiton, you can do like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    id                        serial not null primary key,
    values1                   smallint[] not null DEFAULT ARRAY [12, 20],
    values2                   smallint[] not null DEFAULT '{}',
    CONSTRAINT values1_check CHECK ( values1 <> '{}' ),
    CONSTRAINT values2_check CHECK ( values2 <> '{}' )
);
```

Comment: I am applying this creation and it is not throwing an error!

Comment: @chatzich  - Show query, from which  you expect error throwing

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check constraint:

```
alter table table1 add constraint check_table1_arrays
    check (cardinality(values1) > 0 and cardinality(values2) > 0);
```

Comment: Must I use `alter table` or can I add the check to the table creation?